# PostGIS query with Lon Lat

Tags: postgis

Need SQL syntax for ...
I have a table with individual polygons like a jigsaw puzzle. 
Given a Lon Lat, I need to find the polygon where the lon lat in located.
I am trying:

```
select * from "parcels_06003" where "geom" @ ('-120.0077874119654', '38.71168052297362')
```

geom is my polygon column in the db.

Answer (score 4):

Use for example [ST_Within](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Within.html):

```
SELECT * FROM "parcels_06003"
WHERE ST_Within (ST_PointFromText('POINT(-120.0077874119654 38.71168052297362)', 4326), geom);
```

You were vague on how you provide lat/lon, so the point construction may need tweaking. The 4326 is the SRID of the WGS84 projection.

Continuing from the comments, your projection is [SR-ORG:15](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/15/), very similar to 4269, so you can try with 4269 first or follow the PostGIS insertion link on the page to add it (if it isn't present already as 915).

Comment: it is 4326 projection, but I got this error:  ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries

********** Error **********

ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
SQL state: XX000

Comment: how do I veryify the project for this imported table?

Comment: you mean your table is also using 4326? The error says that both geometries need to use the same projection, so if you're taking the points from another table with a different projection, they need to be reprojected first.

Comment: See http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Transform.html for how to do that.

Comment: I mean, when the file is uploaded it defaults to 4236 proj. How do find out what the source file project is?

Comment: I found this in the *.prj file: GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Comment: I know this is an old question, but shouldn't the geom and the point be reversed? `ST_Within(point, geom)`. As shown in the [linked example](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Within.html), `ST_Within(bigcircle,smallcircle)` is false, but `ST_Within(smallcircle,bigcircle)` is true